# Using libjasypt on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, encryption, shell-script, apt-get

When I install libjasypt with Ubuntu, where does it install, and where can I find the encrypt/decrypt.sh scripts?

I used the following command to install jasypt.

```
sudo apt-get install libjasypt-java
```

I'm attempting to use jasypt to encrypt/decrypt values intended for use in properties files, but cannot seem to find the scripts needed to actually perform the work on the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `dpkg -L libjasypt-java` to list the files belonging to that package.

Comment: This provides a list of what was installed, but it doesn't look like the encrypt.sh and decrypt.sh scripts I was expecting were included.

Do you think I missed something, or installed the wrong package? I couldn't find other packages for jasypt in the ubuntu repos.

Comment: What made you think the package had those files?

Comment: Perhaps awkward assumption that jasypt and libjasypt were the same?

Admittedly RTFM on my part.

The following link indicates you need to download from the jasypt Sourceforge repo to get the scripts.

[link](http://www.jasypt.org/cli.html)

However, libjasypt is a dependency for the web application I'm working on anyway. Optimistically misconstrued. ;-)